# Can find push the filenames of the found files into the pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-findutils

I would like to do a find in some `dir`, and do a `awk` on the files in this direcory, and then replace the original files by each result.

```
find dir | xargs cat | awk ... | mv ... > filename
```

So I need the filename (of each of the files found by find) in the last command. How can I do that?

Comment: What problem you are got in this ?

Comment: write a script and pass the filename `find dir -exec myscript {} \;` where myscript starts with like `name="$1"`and the does the cat, the awk etc.

Comment: `xargs cat` here is pointless (and won't work because it'll combine files). `xargs awk` would be better (and would let `awk` handle each file independently, including running `mv` if you really want).

Comment: Where are you expecting to write the content from `awk` with this sort of pipeline? You need a file for `mv` to operate on (and it doesn't read from standard input. You *could* have `awk` (with `xargs awk`) write to a temporary file and then have it print the new and old names to standard output and then use `xargs mv` (with it limited to two entries per-comand) but that's overly complicated for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop, like:

```
for filename in `find . -name "*test_file*" -print0 | xargs -0`
do
    # some processing, then
    echo "what you like" > "$filename"
done
```

EDIT: as noted in the comments, the benefits of `-print0 | xargs -0` are lost because of the `for` loop. And filenames containing a white space are still not handled correctly.

The following `while` loop would not handle unusual filenames neither (good to know it, though it was not in the question), but filenames with a standard white space at least, so it works better, indeed:

```
find . -name "*test*file*" -print > files_list

while IFS= read -r filename
do
    # some process
    echo "what you like" > "$filename"
done < files_list
```

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if you can do this by starrting with `find dir`, not with `for f in $(find dir)`

Comment: Maybe you could add this precision in your question? Without storing the filenames somewhere, I don't know how you can get them back after several commands.

Comment: `find dir | while read filename` will behave very similar and *does* start with find dir - but zezollos answer covers cases e.g. with newlines in filenames that would not be handled by this - but nobody really understands why you are keen to "start with `find dir`"

Comment: This answer does *not* handle filenames with newlines/spaces, etc. in the names. Any safety on that front that you gain from `-print0` and `-0` you lose immediately (and worse) by using `for filename in \`...\``. Because you shouldn't [read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @EtanReisner ...and by redirecting to the unquoted `$filename`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, you're right but quoting `$filename` is not enough

Comment: @zezollo No, I just added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like this (but I wouldn't recommend it at all).

```
find dir -print0 |
    xargs -0 -n 2 awk -v OFS='\0' '<process the input and write to temporary file>
        END {print "temporaryfile", FILENAME}' |
    xargs -0 -n 2 mv
```

This passes the files to `awk` directly two at a time (which avoids the problem with your original where `cat` will get hundreds (perhaps more) files as arguments all at once and spit **all** their content at `awk` via standard input at once and thus lose their individual contents and filenames entirely).

It then has `awk` write the processed output to a temporary file and then outputs the temporary filename and the original filename where `xargs` picks them up (again two at a time) and runs `mv` on the pairs of temporary file/original file names.

As I said at the beginning however this is a terrible way to do this.

If you have a new enough version of `GNU awk` (version 4.1.0 or newer) then you could just use the `-i` (in-place) argument to `awk` and use (I believe):

```
find dir | xargs awk -i '......'
```

Without that I would use a `while` loop of the form in [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to read the `find` output line-by-line and operate on it in the loop.